# Native android menu not showing in Phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-menu

The android native menu is not opening when pressing menu button while using `PhoneGap`. When I am pressing `menu` button, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method is getting called but the menu is not getting created.

```
public class PhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        Log.d("Menu","Menu option called");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.phone_gap, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The log is getting printed, that means the function is getting called.

XML file for menu: When the `android:showAsAction` is set to `always` its showing in the action bar, otherwise its not working.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings_holo_light"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/more"/>

</menu>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. The bug was in PhoneGap 2.6. I downloaded PhoneGap version 2.5 and it worked normally.

Comment: This will be fixed in PhoneGap 2.8 - see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/niJG55vtLCs .