# Eclipse Android OptionMenu in PhoneGap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I am developing an web app and I need to include an Option Menu which will contain an About Section of the app).

What I did was the following:

Settings.xml (found under xml folder)

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference android:key="music" android:title="@string/music_title" android:summary="@string/music_summary"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="hints" android:title="@string/hints_title" android:summary="@string/hints_summary"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Prefs.java class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
```

In Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.example.testphonegap.Prefs"
    android:label="@string/action_settings">
</activity>
```

In my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ldpi);
    super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading Silver Angel ...");
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 50000); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",50000);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.about:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
  return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

Now the problem is that when I press the About menu, the app closes and no errors occur. The only thing that I have in the log is the following:

```
12-10 11:53:19.944: D/CordovaActivity(1141): Paused the application!
12-10 11:53:19.944: D/CordovaWebView(1141): Handle the pause
12-10 11:53:20.604: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1141): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-10 11:53:22.054: D/CordovaActivity(1141): CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
12-10 11:53:22.054: D/CordovaWebView(1141): >>> loadUrlNow()
12-10 11:53:22.204: D/CordovaActivity(1141): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
12-10 11:53:22.685: D/Cordova(1141): onPageFinished(about:blank)
12-10 11:53:22.685: D/CordovaActivity(1141): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
12-10 11:53:22.685: D/CordovaActivity(1141): onMessage(exit,null)
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong please so that I can solve this small issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same what you have asked the same question already been answered

[Native android menu not showing in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045329/native-android-menu-not-showing-in-phonegap)

Comment: your cord-ova version is 3.0 above